# Is it possible to create a function to shortcut module functions?

Tags: python, telegram

```
@BOT.message_handler(commands=['drink'])
def drink(message):
    try:
        BOT.send_message(message.chat.id, f'I added {message.text.split(" ", 2)[1]} to your daily intake for today, {fecha_excel}!')

    except IndexError:
        BOT.send_message(message.chat.id, 'IndexError')
```

I basically want to create a function to shorten the "BOT.send_message(message.chat.id," part, since it will always be the same (at least for this project)

I tried creating this function inside the (handler? method? the @ thingy):

`def send(message): BOT.send_message(message.chat.id, message)`

And then in the drink() function, change it to:

```
@BOT.message_handler(commands=['drink'])
def drink(message):
    try:
        send(f'I added {message.text.split(" ", 2)[1]} to your daily intake for today, {fecha_excel}!')

    except IndexError:
        send('IndexError')
```

That doesn't work because it doesn't need a string but a "chat" object (if I understood correctly the error message), but is there any way to make it work?
This project should be fairly simple and short, so I won't lose too much time typing "BOT.send_message(message.chat.id,", but in the future it might save me some time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid using `message` or `message.chat.id` completely. The best (shortest) you can do is:

```
def respond(message, text):
   BOT.send_message(message.chat.id, text)

@BOT.message_handler(commands=['drink'])
def drink(message):
    try:
        respond(message, f'I added {message.text.split(" ", 2)[1]} to your daily intake for today, {fecha_excel}!')
    except IndexError:
        respond(message, 'IndexError')
```

Although, doesn't `Message` have [.reply_text(text)](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_text)?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest I don't know how to see what it "has". IIRC, I can see attributes with `dir()`, but those are... What are they exactly? Functions I guess?

Edit: what's the reason why I can't avoid using `message` or `message.chat.id`? I assume lots of people have already come up with a similar idea but never thought it was good (or at all possible) to implement it, so why is it a bad idea to change how python works (or whatever would need a change) to make my `send()` function work?

Comment: Okay, I was using a different module (telebot, not telegram), I will start using telegram now since the documentation is much better organized and explained, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the helper function to take two arguments, `chat_id` and `text` :

```
def send(chat_id, text):
    BOT.send_message(chat_id, text)
```

Then in the drink function, change it to:

```
@BOT.message_handler(commands=['drink'])
def drink(message):
    try:
        send(message.chat.id, f'I added {message.text.split(" ", 2)[1]} to your daily intake for today, {fecha_excel}!')

    except IndexError:
        send(message.chat.id, 'IndexError')
```

Now use the helper function `send` to send messages to the chat with a given chat id and text.